# App got approved, iAd not showing up

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, iad

My app has just got approved and unfortunately my iAd banner is white blank.

I've configured iAd on iTunes Connect.

Thanks,

Comment: You may need to give it a little time. You have iAds configured on iTunes connect for this app right?

Comment: Offtopic: how long it took Apple to approve your app?

Comment: Are you only displaying your banner when an ad is actually available?

Comment: It takes about 5-7 days from app submission until going into review.

Comment: The only the iAd banner is being displayed, I submitted my app on June 1, and it approved today

Comment: Did you implement a fallback in case iAds are not loading? In many countries there aren't enough advertisers to display ads

Comment: I downloaded my app using an USA account... and it's still white blank

Comment: When you say you configured your add in Itunes connect do you mean you actually Signed the contract to display iAd's? Because contracts need to be signed and approved.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704253/adbannerview-fails-to-receive-ad-with-error-the-operation-couldnt-be-completed/22990407#22990407

It worked fine to me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's worth noting that if you run your app in debug, you'll get confirmation on whether the system you've implemented works, as you'll be getting test ads appearing (Grey adverts with Apple branding, clicking on one will show a message saying test adverts are working). If this is not the case, then there is an issue with the code. You'll need to disclose that code for additional help.

If the test ads do work, then it can be attributed to some/all of these issues.

1. You've not set up iAd correctly in iTunes connect for your application. You need to enable it in the 'Manage Your Applications' section of iTunes connect.
2. You haven't correctly set up the iAd contracts. See the 'Contracts, Tax, and Banking' section of iTunes connect, and make sure iAd Network for the World region is all in order.
3. There aren't any advertisements to display. You won't get adverts being shown 24/7, they will only appear at particular times (this is working as designed). Test the app store build of your application over a long period of time, to see if ads appear. Note that different regions will get ads at different frequencies (the USA being most popular I believe).
   Note: The iAd framework provides methods to determine whether an advert is ready to be shown (see `bannerViewWillLoadAd:` and `bannerViewDidLoadAd:` in ADBannerViewDelegate for example). You should only make room for an iAd banner when there is an advert available, otherwise your app should look like there was never a banner there to begin with. Otherwise you'll end up with white space as you've mentioned

Comment: even I checked my iAd contracts and I have enabled iAd in the app there are still no ads showing up. I'm from Slovakia and I'm pretty sure there are lot of ads to show up (as seen in other apps). Anyway, how can I be sure my iAd contract is OK?

Comment: Same situation. I have submitted app from Hungary for two weeks, no ad have appeard on clients yet. More than 100 clients were already downloaded it. I can see in Sales and Trends some of the client are from USA. Strange. Have you changed your code afterward, latter on in last year **have you made any revenue with ads**?