# No iAd banner in app downloaded from ituens

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

Apple has recently approved my app which contains iAd BannerView. While in both iOS Simulator and testing device iAd BannerView shows OK, in app downloaded right form Appstore is no iAd BannerView. I already enabled iAd Advertising Network so I can't figure out where is the problem. Could you guys help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is no iAd available in your region. For testing cases when developing the app with development profiles, iAds show up every time to help the developer. For production apps, iAds should be available in that territory in order to show up.

Comment: What do you mean there is no iAd available? I'm from Slovakia and I saw many apps with iAd bar with Slovak advertisements.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954681/app-got-approved-iad-not-showing-up

Comment: even I checked my iAd contracts and I have enabled iAd in the app there are still no ads showing up. any idea?